# Controlling width of column of nested grid which is an item in outer grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'd like to create a grid of such elements:

[image]

What is my grid goal:

- Minimum one column, no max column count (as much as user screen can hold).
- To be able to set column and row gap. E.g. 1em.

What's my item goal:

- To be able to set min and max width, e.g. 300px - 1fr.
- To be able to set padding, e.g. 1em.
- Item should consist of two columns.
- To be able to set a gap between the two columns, e.g. 1em.
- Left column has fixed width, e.g. 50px.
- Right column should take the rest of available width.

Left column is going to contain a fixed-size image. There will be no overflow.

What's my right column goal:

- It should consist of two rows.
- To be able to set a gap between the two rows, e.g. 1em.
- The bottom row should have max one line of text. If the text overflows, it should have ellipsis at the right side.
- The upper row should have max four lines of text. If the text overflows, it should have ellipsis at the end.

What I was able to achieve:

- To create the main grid of items.
- If text in the right column of an item doesn't overflow, everything works like a charm.

The problem is when there is a lot of text in the right column of an item. I can't make the right column to not go out of the item. And that's my main problem. Could you please assist me with this?

My current code:
https://jsfiddle.net/u9v041zq

My current CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    color: white;
    background-color: #121212;
    margin: 0;

    line-height: 20px;
}

#grid-container {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-color: #222222;

    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
    column-gap: 1em;
    row-gap: 1em;
}

.grid-item {
    background-color: blue;
    padding: 1em;

    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 50px auto;
    column-gap: 1em;
}

.grid-item-left {
    width: 50px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: brown;
}

.grid-item-right {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: darkcyan;
}

.grid-item-right-top {
    background-color: darkgray;

    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.grid-item-right-bottom {
    background-color: darkgreen;

    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

Examle HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="grid-container">
        
            <div class="grid-item">
                <div class="grid-item-left">
                    left
                </div>

                <div class="grid-item-right">
                    <div class="grid-item-right-top">
                        right top right top right top right top right top right
                        right top right top right top right top right top right
                        right top right top right top right top right top right
                        right top right top right top right top right top right
                        right top right top right top right top right top right
                        right top right top right top right top right top right
                        right top right top right top right top right top right
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid-item-right-bottom">
                        right bottommmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        
            <div class="grid-item">
                <div class="grid-item-left">
                    left
                </div>

                <div class="grid-item-right">
                    <div class="grid-item-right-top">
                        right top right top right top right top right top right
                        right top right top right top right top right top right
                        right top right top right top right top right top right
                        right top right top right top right top right top right
                        right top right top right top right top right top right
                        right top right top right top right top right top right
                        right top right top right top right top right top right
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid-item-right-bottom">
                        right bottommmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        
            <div class="grid-item">
                <div class="grid-item-left">
                    left
                </div>

                <div class="grid-item-right">
                    <div class="grid-item-right-top">
                        right top right top right top right top right top right
                        right top right top right top right top right top right
                        right top right top right top right top right top right
                        right top right top right top right top right top right
                        right top right top right top right top right top right
                        right top right top right top right top right top right
                        right top right top right top right top right top right
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid-item-right-bottom">
                        right bottommmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        
            <div class="grid-item">
                <div class="grid-item-left">
                    left
                </div>

                <div class="grid-item-right">
                    <div class="grid-item-right-top">
                        right top right top right top right top right top right
                        right top right top right top right top right top right
                        right top right top right top right top right top right
                        right top right top right top right top right top right
                        right top right top right top right top right top right
                        right top right top right top right top right top right
                        right top right top right top right top right top right
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid-item-right-bottom">
                        right bottommmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        
            <div class="grid-item">
                <div class="grid-item-left">
                    left
                </div>

                <div class="grid-item-right">
                    <div class="grid-item-right-top">
                        right top right top right top right top right top right
                        right top right top right top right top right top right
                        right top right top right top right top right top right
                        right top right top right top right top right top right
                        right top right top right top right top right top right
                        right top right top right top right top right top right
                        right top right top right top right top right top right
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid-item-right-bottom">
                        right bottommmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        
            <div class="grid-item">
                <div class="grid-item-left">
                    left
                </div>

                <div class="grid-item-right">
                    <div class="grid-item-right-top">
                        right top right top right top right top right top right
                        right top right top right top right top right top right
                        right top right top right top right top right top right
                        right top right top right top right top right top right
                        right top right top right top right top right top right
                        right top right top right top right top right top right
                        right top right top right top right top right top right
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid-item-right-bottom">
                        right bottommmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        
            <div class="grid-item">
                <div class="grid-item-left">
                    left
                </div>

                <div class="grid-item-right">
                    <div class="grid-item-right-top">
                        right top right top right top right top right top right
                        right top right top right top right top right top right
                        right top right top right top right top right top right
                        right top right top right top right top right top right
                        right top right top right top right top right top right
                        right top right top right top right top right top right
                        right top right top right top right top right top right
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid-item-right-bottom">
                        right bottommmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        
            <div class="grid-item">
                <div class="grid-item-left">
                    left
                </div>

                <div class="grid-item-right">
                    <div class="grid-item-right-top">
                        right top right top right top right top right top right
                        right top right top right top right top right top right
                        right top right top right top right top right top right
                        right top right top right top right top right top right
                        right top right top right top right top right top right
                        right top right top right top right top right top right
                        right top right top right top right top right top right
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid-item-right-bottom">
                        right bottommmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        
            <div class="grid-item">
                <div class="grid-item-left">
                    left
                </div>

                <div class="grid-item-right">
                    <div class="grid-item-right-top">
                        right top right top right top right top right top right
                        right top right top right top right top right top right
                        right top right top right top right top right top right
                        right top right top right top right top right top right
                        right top right top right top right top right top right
                        right top right top right top right top right top right
                        right top right top right top right top right top right
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid-item-right-bottom">
                        right bottommmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        
            <div class="grid-item">
                <div class="grid-item-left">
                    left
                </div>

                <div class="grid-item-right">
                    <div class="grid-item-right-top">
                        right top right top right top right top right top right
                        right top right top right top right top right top right
                        right top right top right top right top right top right
                        right top right top right top right top right top right
                        right top right top right top right top right top right
                        right top right top right top right top right top right
                        right top right top right top right top right top right
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid-item-right-bottom">
                        right bottommmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

alike flex, you will need to set min-width:x or overflow:hidden to the parent, so it force a reflow and calculation : https://jsfiddle.net/r18snq9c/

```
.grid-item-right {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: darkcyan;      
 /* fixed behavior here */    min-width:0;
}
```

About clamping at the forth line ,you can do : *(see: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/l/line-clamp/ )*

```
.grid-item-right-top {
  /* update */
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 4;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  /* end update*/
  background-color: darkgray;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

demo

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  background-color: #121212;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 20px;
}

#grid-container {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background-color: #222222;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  column-gap: 1em;
  row-gap: 1em;
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 1em;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50px auto;
  column-gap: 1em;
}

.grid-item-left {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: brown;
}

.grid-item-right {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: darkcyan;
  /* fixed behavior here */
  min-width: 0;
}

.grid-item-right-top {
  /* update */
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 4;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  /* end update*/
  background-color: darkgray;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.grid-item-right-bottom {
  background-color: darkgreen;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="grid-container">

    <div class="grid-item">
      <div class="grid-item-left">
        left
      </div>

      <div class="grid-item-right">
        <div class="grid-item-right-top">
          right top right top right top right top right top right right top right top right top right top right top right right top right top right top right top right top right right top right top right top right top right top right right top right top right top
          right top right top right right top right top right top right top right top right right top right top right top right top right top right
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item-right-bottom">
          right bottommmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-item">
      <div class="grid-item-left">
        left
      </div>

      <div class="grid-item-right">
        <div class="grid-item-right-top">
          right top right top right top right top right top right right top right top right top right top right top right right top right top right top right top right top right right top right top right top right top right top right right top right top right top
          right top right top right right top right top right top right top right top right right top right top right top right top right top right
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item-right-bottom">
          right bottommmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-item">
      <div class="grid-item-left">
        left
      </div>

      <div class="grid-item-right">
        <div class="grid-item-right-top">
          right top right top right top right top right top right right top right top right top right top right top right right top right top right top right top right top right right top right top right top right top right top right right top right top right top
          right top right top right right top right top right top right top right top right right top right top right top right top right top right
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item-right-bottom">
          right bottommmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-item">
      <div class="grid-item-left">
        left
      </div>

      <div class="grid-item-right">
        <div class="grid-item-right-top">
          right top right top right top right top right top right right top right top right top right top right top right right top right top right top right top right top right right top right top right top right top right top right right top right top right top
          right top right top right right top right top right top right top right top right right top right top right top right top right top right
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item-right-bottom">
          right bottommmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-item">
      <div class="grid-item-left">
        left
      </div>

      <div class="grid-item-right">
        <div class="grid-item-right-top">
          right top right top right top right top right top right right top right top right top right top right top right right top right top right top right top right top right right top right top right top right top right top right right top right top right top
          right top right top right right top right top right top right top right top right right top right top right top right top right top right
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item-right-bottom">
          right bottommmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-item">
      <div class="grid-item-left">
        left
      </div>

      <div class="grid-item-right">
        <div class="grid-item-right-top">
          right top right top right top right top right top right right top right top right top right top right top right right top right top right top right top right top right right top right top right top right top right top right right top right top right top
          right top right top right right top right top right top right top right top right right top right top right top right top right top right
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item-right-bottom">
          right bottommmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-item">
      <div class="grid-item-left">
        left
      </div>

      <div class="grid-item-right">
        <div class="grid-item-right-top">
          right top right top right top right top right top right right top right top right top right top right top right right top right top right top right top right top right right top right top right top right top right top right right top right top right top
          right top right top right right top right top right top right top right top right right top right top right top right top right top right
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item-right-bottom">
          right bottommmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-item">
      <div class="grid-item-left">
        left
      </div>

      <div class="grid-item-right">
        <div class="grid-item-right-top">
          right top right top right top right top right top right right top right top right top right top right top right right top right top right top right top right top right right top right top right top right top right top right right top right top right top
          right top right top right right top right top right top right top right top right right top right top right top right top right top right
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item-right-bottom">
          right bottommmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-item">
      <div class="grid-item-left">
        left
      </div>

      <div class="grid-item-right">
        <div class="grid-item-right-top">
          right top right top right top right top right top right right top right top right top right top right top right right top right top right top right top right top right right top right top right top right top right top right right top right top right top
          right top right top right right top right top right top right top right top right right top right top right top right top right top right
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item-right-bottom">
          right bottommmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-item">
      <div class="grid-item-left">
        left
      </div>

      <div class="grid-item-right">
        <div class="grid-item-right-top">
          right top right top right top right top right top right right top right top right top right top right top right right top right top right top right top right top right right top right top right top right top right top right right top right top right top
          right top right top right right top right top right top right top right top right right top right top right top right top right top right
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item-right-bottom">
          right bottommmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That nails the problem with width! Thank you. I'll try to solve four-lines-and-ellipsis problem on my own.

Comment: @stryku take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-line-clamp -/- https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/l/line-clamp/ I updated the snippet

Comment: @stryku i updated the snippet to clamp at the forth line ;)

Comment: I'd accept the answer once again if I could. Thank you again!